# ErrorTemplate on Control within UserControl

Tags: wpf, validation

I'm much more of a reader here on stackoverflow than a writer, but I'm getting desperate on this probably fast to answer question. The solutions I found so far don't fix my problem:
While the validating and display of the correct ErrorTemplate for the TextBox in the following Window-code works (the ViewModel behind the binding implements INotifyDataErrorInfo), the exact same code for a TextBox moved into a custom usercontrol (controls:LabeledTextField), won't.

```
<Window x:Class="ValidationErrorTemplateTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ValidationErrorTemplateTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    Height="300"
    Width="300"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Width="100" Height="20" Text="{Binding WelcomeTitle, NotifyOnValidationError=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
        ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorHint}" Margin="40"/>
    <controls:LabeledTextField Value="{Binding WelcomeTitle}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Skins/MainSkin.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationErrorHint">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <Border Background="Red" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="12" Height="12" CornerRadius="6" 
                    ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=customAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}">
                <TextBlock Text="!" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" FontSize="10"/>
            </Border>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="customAdorner" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
        </DockPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This is the xaml for LabeledTextField:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ValidationErrorTemplateTest.LabeledTextField"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="340">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="Root">
    <TextBox Width="100" Height="20" Text="{Binding Value, NotifyOnValidationError=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
        ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorHint}"/>
</Grid>
```

and the codebehind:

```
namespace ValidationErrorTemplateTest
{
    public partial class LabeledTextField : UserControl
    {
        public LabeledTextField()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Root.DataContext = this;
        }

        public string Value
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(LabeledTextField), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
    }
}
```

I read about adding a `<ArdornerDecorator>`-Layer but it doesn't seem to corret the problem. 
I assume somehow the ErrorTemplate of the usercontrol is used instead of the one assigned to the TextBox within the usercontrol, but I have no clue how to fix that. Any hint would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work. I just used the code you pasted here and made my version of the application.

My `MainWindow`:

```
<Window x:Class="ErrorTemplateNotWorking.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ErrorTemplateNotWorking"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Width="100" Height="20" 
                     Text="{Binding WelcomeTitle, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                     Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorHint}" 
                     Margin="40"/>
            <local:LabeledTextField Value="{Binding WelcomeTitle, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                                    Width="100" Height="20"
                                    Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorHint}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note that I only use the `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True` in the bindings and I set the `Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorHint}"` for the `UserControl` as well. Another important thing is to set a `Width` and `Height` for the `UserControl` so the validation exclamation mark can't get outside the window's bounds, because the control would just stretch to its max width without this.

The code-behind of my `MainWindow`:

```
namespace ErrorTemplateNotWorking
{
    using System.Windows;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using Annotations;

    public class MainWindowViewModel : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get {
                if (columnName == nameof(WelcomeTitle))
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(WelcomeTitle) || WelcomeTitle.Length < 5)
                    {
                        return "Title should be at least 5 characters long";
                    }
                }

                return "";
            }
        }

        public string Error => null;

        private string _welcomeTitle;
        public string WelcomeTitle
        {
            get { return _welcomeTitle; }
            set
            {
                _welcomeTitle = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WelcomeTitle));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using some ReSharper and C# 6 features, but the gist should be understandable. Basically I'm just setting the DataContext to the VM and in the VM I implement the `IDataErrorInfo` with a validation rule that the text should be at least 5 characters long.

The MainSkin.xaml is the same.

And the UserControl XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ErrorTemplateNotWorking.LabeledTextField"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="Root">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here I don't even need anything extra on the `Binding`.
And the result is:

[image: Result]

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much! this worked!
None the less I feel disappointed about wpf: I hoped I could shift the declarative stuff from all my textboxes to one usercontrol-template. 
Having to add `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"  Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorHint}"` everywhere around my project is quite an ugly code clutterage.